# Utilizing indexes in CouchDB for $in queries

Tags: database, couchdb

Say I have documents of the following structure in my CouchDB database:

```js
{
    "_id": "02e03006fc8870c3ae556e9b6654f823",
    "type": "purchase",
    "item_id": 1000,
    // ...
}
```

And I want to query (with Mango queries) them like so:

```js
{
   "selector": {
      "item_id": {
         "$in": [1234, 7890]
      },
      "type": "purchase"
   }
}
```

Is there a way to make this query efficient with indexes? I tried a combined index on `item_id, type`, but even though it's being used, the number of examined documents is still basically my whole database and thus quite slow. Of course, when only searching for a single `item_id`, the query is super fast, but apparently the array search using `$in` kills performance.